# remove saved passphrase for ssh key

Tags: ssh

unlike several questions I found. I do not want to save my passphrase when I connect to the server with my ssh key.

I mistakenly ticked the box "remember my passphrase" and now the connection ssh is done without asking for my passphrase and I can not manage to make the system forget it.

I already tried `ssh-add -D` without success.

Comment: Any particular OS/distro/DE?

Comment: yes, Kali linux

Comment: desktop environment keyring service?

Comment: yes I think that's it!

Answer (score 2):

It's not `ssh-agent -d`. That would start an SSH agent with debugging turned on.

Instead, use

```
ssh-add -d
```

to remove the default identity from the agent.  You may also add the paths to the specific key files whose identities you'd like to remove from the agent.

Use

```
ssh-add -D
```

to delete *all* identities from the agent.

See the manual for `ssh-add` on your system.

Comment: Yes, sorry that's what I tried (`ssh-add -D`)

Comment: I have edited my question to correct this mistake.